# How to avoid sudo -i for update

Tags: apt, sudo

I am using Ubuntu 16..

I want to run the following command

```
apt-get update
```

It is working after executing the following

```
sudo -i
```

and exporting http_proxy.

But when I execute

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after exporting http_proxy, the command results in error. How can I run `apt-get update` without having to use a root shell?

Comment: Yep, not updating.

Comment: Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
................................................................................................................